# Reordering todo lists in trello cards

Tags: trello-cards

is there a way to reorder todo lists within a card? If not, I would like to see such a feature implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Trello now has checklist reordering.  ([source](https://twitter.com/trello/status/302121256986222593))

---

Since the lists sort alphabetically/numerically, a simple workaround is to number them.  E.g.:

1 - My first feature

2 - Another feature

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if this feature is under consideration. Lots of discussion about it on the [Trello development board](https://trello.com/card/reorder-checklists-drag-items-between-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1073).